# In CDC, Not able to read the data from CDC function but the DB_Owner can read it what permission should I get

Tags: sql-server, cdc

In CDC, Not able to read the  data from CDC function but any user in DB_Owner can read it what permission should I get ? whenever I call this function I get empty records
`cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_instance(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'ALL')`
[image]

but the same exact script when the other Db_Owner 's users can see the records
Any specific Role or permission should I get without granting the db_owner ? !
Please NOte I am able to see the data from the CDC table directly :
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions)? I'd also validate that it's indeed a problem with that function and not the LSN values being passed to it by hardcoding them in a test script.